# NoMethodError in Users#mypage undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This line in my code:

```
<%= simple_form_for @category, :url => url_for(:action => 'bookfinal', :controller => 'users'), :method => 'post' do |f| %>
```

is throwing me this error:

> NoMethodError in Users#mypage undefined method `model_name' for
>   nil:NilClass

And I'm not quite sure why? See full code below:

**users/mypage.html.erb**

```
<div id="widepage">
  <div class="bpage">     
    <div class="bcol">      
      <div class="blue-text-header">Book</div>
      <div class="grey-text-subheader">Ask a question</div>

      <br><br>
      <div class="infoheaders">1. Question
        <%= simple_form_for @category, :url => url_for(:action => 'bookfinal', :controller => 'users'), :method => 'post' do |f| %>
          <%= f.collection_select(:title, Category.all, :title, :title) %>
          <div class="grey-text-subheader">Device: (optional)</div>
          <%= f.check_box :Apple %> <%= f.label "Apple" %> &nbsp; &nbsp; 
          <%= f.check_box :iPhone %> <%= f.label "iPhone" %> &nbsp; &nbsp;  
          <%= f.check_box :iPad %> <%= f.label "iPad" %> &nbsp; &nbsp; 
          <%= f.check_box :Mac %> <%= f.label "Mac" %> &nbsp; &nbsp;  
          <%= f.check_box :Android %> <%= f.label "Android" %><br><br>
          <%= f.check_box :Samsung %> <%= f.label "Samsung" %> &nbsp; &nbsp;  
          <%= f.check_box :Microsoft %> <%= f.label "Microsoft" %>&nbsp; &nbsp; 
          <%= f.check_box :Windows %> <%= f.label "Windows" %> &nbsp; &nbsp; 
          <%= f.check_box :Google %> <%= f.label "Google" %> 
          <%= f.button :submit, 'Submit' %>
        <% end %>
      </div>


      <div class="bcol">        
        <div class="card">          
          <div class="columns">
            <div class="col">
              <%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:thumb), :class => 'round-image-125' %>            
              <br><br>

              <font color="#ee4d50" font size="3">
                <b>Services:</b>
              </font>
            </div>            

            <div class="coltechie">
              <div class="techie-name">
              <%= @user.firstname %><%= @user.lastname %>              
              </div>
            </div>

            <br>
            <font color="#4d4d4d" font size="3">
              <b><%= @user.city%>, <%= @user.stateprov%></b>
            </font>

            <br><br>
            <font color="#2c78d3" font size="4">
              <b>Bio:</b>
            </font> 

            <br><br>
            <%= @user.bio%>
            <br><br>

            <font color="#2c78d3" font size="4">
              <b>Categories:</b>
            </font>
          </div>          
        </div>        
      </div>    
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def mypage
    @user = User.new
    @category = Category.new
  end

  def bookfinal
    if params[:category][:ipad].present?
      @checked = params[:category][:ipad]
    end  
    if params[:category][:ipad].present?
      @checked = params[:category][:android]
    end
    if params[:category][:ipad].present?
      @checked = params[:category][:samsung]
    end
  end

end
```

**routes.rb**

```
get "users/bookfinal"
```

**Console:**

```
Started POST "/users/bookfinal" for 96.49.105.234 at 2016-02-19 20:19:02 +0000
Processing by UsersController#bookfinal as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"pVchU8SD2MuypducuRPLcWbFwMg1yXIJWoKNVbRoDj1n5LlQIGhtQsOxsZ3MoO1uUaMe9rnVqVYqaECURW+OfA==", "category"=>{"title"=>"Digital Marketing", "Apple"=>"1", "iPhone"=>"0", "iPad"=>"0", "Mac"=>"0", "Android"=>"0", "Samsung"=>"0", "Microsoft"=>"0", "Windows"=>"0", "Google"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
  Rendered users/bookfinal.html.erb within layouts/application (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 75ms (Views: 73.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Does your `users_controller.rb` has `class UsersController < ApplicationController` at the beginning of the file?

Comment: @FixerRB Yes, it does.

Comment: please find `model_name` invocation in your code and write it in question

Comment: Try using `<%= simple_form_for Category.new, :url => url_for(:action => 'bookfinal', :controller => 'users'), :method => 'post' do |f| %>` instead of `<%= simple_form_for @category, :url => url_for(:action => 'bookfinal', :controller => 'users'), :method => 'post' do |f| %>`

Comment: @FixerRB Doing that causes other items pulled from @ category on my page to throw an undefined error... e.g. <%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:thumb), :class => 'round-image-125' %> further down my page, 'avatar' is now undefined.

Comment: Replace `@user = User.new` with `@user = User.all` in users_controller.rb

Comment: @FixerRB Changing to @ user = User.all gives me this error still: undefined method `avatar' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007ffa367ba290>

Comment: @FixerRB Ok wait, all of a sudden I don't get an error when I hit that page anymore. NOW, when I hit the Submit button though, I get this: The action 'create' could not be found for CategoriesController - I'm simply trying to post data to the new page (bookfinal.html.erb)? Do I need a create action in categories_controller?

Comment: @FixerRB See full code added above (users/mypage.html.erb). I've created the route post 'users/bookfinal' - and now the submit button takes me to users/bookfinal page. However it doesn't seem to post/print the checked values and I'm not sure why.

Comment: @FixerRB Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103991/discussion-between-brittany-and-fixerrb).